# Looking for a Synonym for the word "Desire" or "Whims" but applied to a political context

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for a Synonym for the word "Desire", "Whims" or "Quarrels" but applied to a political context. I can't think of the word off the top of my head, but I know the context in which it is used.

For example, you can say

> Hitler appealed to the masses of the German
> people, because he appealed to their "quarrels"

It's not that they appealed to their desires, but they appealed to their need for change and wanted to right their wrongs. He also appealed to their quarrels, or the things that bothered the populace the most. There is a word that is perfect for this context that is very similar to "quarrels", but I cant quite think of it.

Comment: Did he appeal to their **disaffections**? I have a long list of [synonyms](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/quarrel.html) but it's hard to know which one you'll want for  "Desire", "Whims" or "Quarrels".

Comment: ...or perhaps _grievances_?

Comment: All these answers are obviously right, but the one I was thinking of was grievances! Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The word I was thinking of was *grievances.*